# JS within PHP.. alert doesn't show up

Tags: php, javascript

Edited : I've changed the code as follows and getting an 'NaN' error! Can someone give me a clue as to what that is and a tip to solve? Thanks.

---

Can someone please tell me whats wrong with this code?

1. Firstly, I've called a Javascript within PHP, and is it really possible?
2. Is there an issue with the way I've called the second alert? (despite whether its possible or not to use js within php) that meant to display the text input and the option selected in a alert message.
3. Do I need to put 'end of the line' (;) after the last curly bracket of the loop?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die ("Server connection failure!");
$db=mysql_select_db('regional_data',$con) or die ("Couldn't connect the database");
$SQL="SELECT sbstart, sbend FROM newchk";
$run=mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL Error");
$nor=mysql_num_rows($run);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateData() {
var TextIn = document.getElementById('txtN');
    if(TextIn.value == ""){
        alert ("Text field is empty"); 
        return false;
    }else{
        var TextIn = document.getElementById('options');
        alert (<?php $i ?> + TextIn.value);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return ValidateData()" method="POST">
<select STYLE='width:90px'><?php
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($run))
{
    for($i=$rec['sbstart']; $i<=$rec['sbend']; $i++)
    {
        echo "<option id='options' value=''.$i.''>$i<br></option>";
    }
}
?>
</select>
<input type="text" name="txtN">
<input type="submit" name="subN" value="Save">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `textN` defined? Alert won't show up if you have undefined var inside.

Comment: You've used txtN as the name of the input element. To access it like you have, you need to make the id of the element txtN (same with subN)

Comment: For starters use console.log (textN), see what message your getting  using firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the form details in `onsubmit`, your select doesn't have a name, you cannot name the options, you need to name the select box:

```
<form onsubmit="return ValidateData(this)" method="POST">
<select STYLE='width:90px' name='options'><?php
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($run))
{
    for($i=$rec['sbstart']; $i<=$rec['sbend']; $i++)
    {
        echo "<option value='$i'>$i<br></option>";
    }
}
?>
</select>
<input type="text" name="txtN">
<input type="submit" name="subN" value="Save">
</form>
```

and your function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateData(form) {
    if(form.txtN.value == ""){
        alert ("Text field is empty"); 
        return false;
    } else {
        alert (form.options[form.options.selectedIndex].value + form.txtN.value);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. A little clarification. on "alert (form.options[form.options.selectedIndex].value + form.txtN.value); how do I specify the form.options.selectedIndex? is it a inbuilt function?

Comment: If I add the same on the coding it seems that doesnt capture a value and produces an empty output for the select.

Comment: I TAKE BACK THE ABOVE COMMENT. SORTED! MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert (<?php echo $i; ?> + TextIn.value);
```

The way you have you code currently written would output:

```
alert ( + TextIn.value);
```

... which is invalid JS.